# How to listen for changes in Realm with Kotlin Flow in a Repository

Tags: android, realm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to implement the same behavior of how Flow with Room Database in which it already listens to changes. I am pretty confused about how to use the `RealmInstance.toflow()` in which it returns a `Flow<Realm>`, however, I don't want that. If we compare it to Room Database, you can already specify what return type you it to be(ex. `Flow<Entity>`. Since Realm doesn't have any kind of `DAO`s, I am currently left with using

```
 RealmInstance.addChangeListener{
   realm->

//Handle DB Changes here

}
```

I don't know how to integrate the code above in my repository since you cant emit inside the `addChangeListener` because it needs a coroutine however,i don't want a solution of having to create a Global coroutine. I currently have this on my `ItemRepository`:

```
  override suspend fun getItems(): Flow<Resource<List<Item>>> = flow{
    
      RealmInstance.addChangeListener{
       realm->

    //Handle DB Changes here
    //You cant emit() here since it needs a coroutine
    
    }
  }
```

The bottom line problem is: that I want to listen to changes in the realm in which my repository already returns `Flow` of the Object I want.  Something like how Room DB and Flows work.

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-kotlin#observing-data-changes. But it already supports flows? For lists, for a global realm instance, single object, queries and so on. Am I not getting your point?

Comment: I haven't visited the github page for I have only read the Official Documentation. I have followed [https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/install/)( assuming it works both in kotlin and java considering the description from the front page). in setting up Realm on my project, however I can't seem to find the `asFlow` syntax following the code sample from Realm Github Page and only `toFlow` is the currently available.

Comment: I already made a workaround by mapping - `realm.toflow().map {
          it.where(Object::class.java).findAll().toList().map { entity -> entity.toDomain() }` in which it returns the object I want.  However it kinda not the solution I was expecting.

Comment: Okay, got it. Then probably you should consider migrating to the kotlin version of the lib? It's even mentioned on their github page, haha. Because it will have all supported suspend and flow functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to convert a callback listener like Realm changeListener to a Coroutine, you have two options :

One- Using CallBackFlow :

```
    return callbackFlow<Location> {
       RealmInstance.addChangeListener{
       realm->
         trySend(realm.toString()) // for example to return a string
        }
        
       addOnFailureListener { e ->
            close(e)
        }
        awaitClose {
            // remove and close your resources
        }
    }
```

TWO- Use suspendCancellableCoroutine

```
return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
      RealmInstance.addChangeListener{
         realm->

           //Handle DB Changes here
            continuation.resume(returnValue)
          }
       continuation.invokeOnCancellation { 
          // do cleanup
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `asFlow()` function that converts realm result into flow. Official documentation is not clear about it so it's hard to find it.

My code example

```
override fun getUsersFlow(projectId: Int?): Flow<List<UseEntity>> {
    // The use block ensures that the Realm instance is closed properly after its use
    return Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        realm.where(UseEntity::class.java).apply {
            if (projectId != null) equalTo("projectId", projectId)
        }.findAllAsync()
          .toFlow() // Converts the Realm results to Kotlin Flow
          .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main)
          .map { results ->
              // Copy results from Realm from the background thread
              realm.copyFromRealm(results)
                  .sortedByDescending { it.createdTime }
          }
          .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
    }
}
```

Also check out the related post on [How can I copy results from Realm in a background thread while still listening for changes from the main thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77620387/3129644)